# Informatica Repository: How to get the SQL query Stored in SQL Transformation

Tags: repository, transformation, informatica

I want to fetch the following sql query, used in SQL transformation, using INFA repo tables.
In mappings --> sql transformation --> SQL ports --> **SQL query**

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why you can't open informatica client and look in the transformation itself. Only reason that comes to mind is that you don't have permission to log in to the client

Comment: There are lot of such mapping and I want to use speed up the process using tsql.

Answer (score 0):

The data you are looking for is in column `OPB_METAEXT_VAL.PM_VALUE` on the table `OPB_METAEXT_VAL`

```
SELECT *
FROM OPB_METAEXT_VAL
WHERE METAEXT_NAME='SQL_Query'
```

Large Statements may be spread across multiple rows so order by `OPB_METAEXT_VAL.LINE_NO`.

You can join to `OPB_SUBJECT` on `OPB_SUBJECT.SUBJ_ID = OPB_METAEXT_VAL.SUBJECT_ID` to get the folder name.
You can also join to `OPB_WIDGET_INST` on `OPB_WIDGET_INST.WIDGET_ID = OPB_METAEXT_VAL.OBJECT_ID AND OPB_WIDGET_INST.REF_VERSION_NUMBER = OPB_METAEXT_VAL.VERSION_NUMBER`  to get other details about the transformation.

You can then further join to other tables for example if you wanted the folder name, workflow/worklet, session, mapping, transformation, SQL, AND database connection then use the following:

```
  WITH OPB_SESS_CNX_REFS_WRAPPER AS
(
    SELECT OPB_SESS_CNX_REFS.*,
    rank() over(
           partition BY 
                  WORKFLOW_ID, 
                  SESSION_ID, 
                  SESSION_INST_ID, 
                  PROC_INSTANCE_ID  
           order by 
                  VERSION_NUMBER DESC, 
                  SESS_WIDG_INST_ID ASC 
    ) AS  THE_RANK
    FROM OPB_SESS_CNX_REFS
)
SELECT OPB_SUBJECT.SUBJ_NAME AS FOLDER
, WORKFLOW.TASK_NAME AS WORKFLOW_WORKLET_NAME
, OPB_TASK.TASK_NAME AS SESSION_NAME
, OPB_MAPPING.MAPPING_NAME
, OPB_WIDGET_INST.INSTANCE_NAME
, OPB_METAEXT_VAL.PM_VALUE
, OPB_METAEXT_VAL.LINE_NO
,(CASE WHEN OPB_SESS_CNX_REFS_WRAPPER.REF_OBJECT_VALUE IN  ('$Target','$Source') THEN OPB_SESS_CNX_REFS_WRAPPER.REF_OBJECT_VALUE ||'-->' ||OPB_TASK_ATTR.ATTR_VALUE
       ELSE NVL(OPB_SESS_CNX_REFS_WRAPPER.REF_OBJECT_VALUE,OPB_CNX.OBJECT_NAME) END) AS CNX_NAME
FROM       OPB_MAPPING      
INNER JOIN OPB_SUBJECT               ON (OPB_MAPPING.SUBJECT_ID = OPB_SUBJECT.SUBJ_ID 
                                     AND OPB_MAPPING.IS_VISIBLE=1)        
INNER JOIN OPB_WIDGET_INST           ON (OPB_WIDGET_INST.MAPPING_ID = OPB_MAPPING.MAPPING_ID 
                                     AND OPB_WIDGET_INST.VERSION_NUMBER = OPB_MAPPING.VERSION_NUMBER)
LEFT JOIN OPB_WIDGET                 ON (OPB_WIDGET_INST.WIDGET_ID = OPB_WIDGET.WIDGET_ID 
                                     AND OPB_WIDGET.IS_VISIBLE = OPB_MAPPING.IS_VISIBLE)
INNER JOIN OPB_METAEXT_VAL           ON (OPB_METAEXT_VAL.OBJECT_ID = OPB_WIDGET_INST.WIDGET_ID
                                     AND OPB_METAEXT_VAL.VERSION_NUMBER = OPB_WIDGET_INST.REF_VERSION_NUMBER
                                     AND OPB_METAEXT_VAL.METAEXT_NAME='SQL_Query')   
INNER JOIN OPB_SESSION               ON (OPB_SESSION.MAPPING_ID = OPB_MAPPING.MAPPING_ID)
INNER JOIN OPB_TASK                  ON (OPB_SESSION.SESSION_ID = OPB_TASK.TASK_ID 
                                     AND OPB_TASK.IS_VISIBLE = OPB_MAPPING.IS_VISIBLE 
                                     AND OPB_SESSION.VERSION_NUMBER = OPB_TASK.VERSION_NUMBER)
INNER JOIN OPB_TASK         WORKFLOW ON (OPB_TASK.RU_PARENT_ID = WORKFLOW.TASK_ID 
                                     AND WORKFLOW.IS_VISIBLE = OPB_MAPPING.IS_VISIBLE)
INNER JOIN OPB_SWIDGET_INST          ON (OPB_SESSION.SESSION_ID =   OPB_SWIDGET_INST.SESSION_ID 
                                     AND OPB_SESSION.VERSION_NUMBER = OPB_SWIDGET_INST.VERSION_NUMBER 
                                     AND OPB_SWIDGET_INST.INSTANCE_ID = OPB_WIDGET_INST.INSTANCE_ID )
LEFT JOIN OPB_SESS_EXTNS             ON (OPB_SWIDGET_INST.SESSION_ID = OPB_SESS_EXTNS.SESSION_ID 
                                     AND OPB_SWIDGET_INST.VERSION_NUMBER = OPB_SESS_EXTNS.VERSION_NUMBER 
                                     AND OPB_SWIDGET_INST.SESS_WIDG_INST_ID = OPB_SESS_EXTNS.SESS_WIDG_INST_ID)                 
LEFT JOIN OPB_SESS_CNX_REFS_WRAPPER  ON (OPB_SESS_CNX_REFS_WRAPPER.THE_RANK = 1
                                     AND OPB_SESS_EXTNS.SESSION_ID = OPB_SESS_CNX_REFS_WRAPPER.SESSION_ID 
                                     AND OPB_SESS_EXTNS.PROC_INSTANCE_ID = OPB_SESS_CNX_REFS_WRAPPER.PROC_INSTANCE_ID)       
LEFT JOIN  OPB_CNX                   ON (OPB_SESS_CNX_REFS_WRAPPER.REF_OBJECT_TYPE = OPB_CNX.OBJECT_TYPE 
                                     AND OPB_SESS_CNX_REFS_WRAPPER.REF_OBJECT_SUBTYP = OPB_CNX.OBJECT_SUBTYPE 
                                     AND OPB_SESS_CNX_REFS_WRAPPER.REF_OBJECT_ID = OPB_CNX.OBJECT_ID)
LEFT JOIN  OPB_MMD_TASK_ATTR         ON (OPB_SESS_CNX_REFS_WRAPPER.REF_OBJECT_VALUE = SUBSTR(OPB_MMD_TASK_ATTR.ATTR_NAME,1,7) 
                                     AND OPB_SESS_CNX_REFS_WRAPPER.REF_OBJECT_VALUE IN ('$Target','$Source'))
LEFT JOIN  OPB_TASK_ATTR             ON (OPB_TASK_ATTR.TASK_TYPE = OPB_MMD_TASK_ATTR.OBJECT_TYPE_ID 
                                     AND OPB_TASK_ATTR.ATTR_ID = OPB_MMD_TASK_ATTR.ATTR_ID 
                                     AND OPB_TASK_ATTR.TASK_ID = OPB_TASK.TASK_ID 
                                     AND OPB_TASK_ATTR.VERSION_NUMBER = OPB_SWIDGET_INST.VERSION_NUMBER)
WHERE OPB_SUBJECT.SUBJ_NAME = '<YOUR FOLDER NAME>'
ORDER BY OPB_SUBJECT.SUBJ_NAME
, WORKFLOW.TASK_NAME
, OPB_TASK.TASK_NAME
, OPB_MAPPING.MAPPING_NAME
, OPB_WIDGET_INST.INSTANCE_NAME
, OPB_METAEXT_VAL.LINE_NO
```